# While using Vuejs Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: vue.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'
    
    
// Install the vue plugin
Vue.use(VueApollo)
```

I am using @vue/cli 5.0.8 and I get

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')"
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/vue-apollo.js:15:45)
    at ./src/vue-apollo.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:52:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:155:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:402:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:4:69)
    at ./src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:41:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:155:32)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1289:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:200:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1290:53
```

Comment: The plugin is only meant for projects created with vue-cli 3 according to the [documentation](https://vue-cli-plugin-apollo.netlify.app/guide/) (big yellow warning text at the top)

Comment: FYI vue-cli and Vue 2 are no longer maintained and not recommended to use.  If it's a new project, and you want the least amount of trouble, use Vue 3.  Follow Vue [Quick Start](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) guide to scaffold a project then follow [Apollo Installation](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) instructions

Comment: @yoduh Appreciated for the FYI!